# How can I except a part from a UIView for a gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing an app and I want to scroll through different `UIViewControllers` with a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.
Everything works, but there is one thing where I couldn't find a solution for.

I add the `UIGestureRecognizers` like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}
```

Now I want to know if it is possible to except a part of the `self.view` where it is possible to swipe to a different view.
I want to do this around a `UISwitch`.

Can someone please help me?

Best regards,

Lukas Goes

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `UIView` and add it to `self.view`. Those `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` won't work inside that `UIView`.

Comment: So I have to add another UIView above the UISwitch and the place around it?

Comment: you can put your UISwitch inside that view

Comment: Ok, thnx! I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add another `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to the switch, and, on your original swipe gesture recognisers, call `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` on the switch's new recognizer.

Hope that makes sense, it's such a verbose class... :\

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the delegate method of a gesture recognizer : `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`.
In the `touch` parameter, you have many information, like the position in the screen. You can use this position and test if it is above the switch frame. Return `yes` or `no` depending of if you want to trigger the selector associated to the gesture recognizer or not.